# redusing processing time of Database

Tags: mysql

We have two Database i.e. DB-A and DB-B, we have almost more than 5000 tables in DB-A, we daily process our whole Database. Here Processing means we get the data from multiple tables of DB-A and then insert these data into some of the tables of DB-B, now after inserting these data into DB-B, we access these data many times because we need to process the whole data of DB-B. we access these data of DB-B whenever we need to process it, and we need to process it more than 500 time in a day and every time we access only that data which we need to process. Now since we are accessing these database(DB-B) multiple time it requires more than 2 hr time to get processed.
Now the problem is that i want to access the data from DB-A and then wants to process this data and then wants to insert this data into DB-B in one shot. but the constraint is that we have limited resources that is we have only 16 GB ram and we are not in the position to increase ram.

we have done indexing n all but still it is taking almost more than 2 hr time. please suggest me how can i reduce the processing time of this data ?

Comment: Why don't you use replication to keep B always in sync?

Comment: because A changes very frequently in a day.

Comment: That doesn't mean replication cannot handle it. If you want to do point in time analsis it's a trivial matter of pausing replication and restarting it when you are done.